# Proof regarding the Picard iterative process for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Well, first of all, this is my first question and i hope that someone can help me and my classmates with this problem

Show if $\left|\varphi_0(t)- \varphi(t) \right| \leq c \left|t-t_0\right|^d,$ $a \leq t,$ $t_0 \leq b$, $c>0$, $d>0$, then
$$ \left| \varphi_n(t)- \varphi(t) \right| \leq c \left|t-t_0 \right|^{d+1} \left\{ \dfrac{K}{d+1} + \dfrac{ K^2}{(d+1)(d+2)}+ \cdots \right\}  $$

Always when  $\varphi(t)$ is in 
$$G^1=\left\{  (t,x)| \quad \left|t-t_0 \right| \leq c,  \quad\left|x-x_0 \right| \leq M\left|t-t_0 \right|  \right\}$$ i.e. a close and bounded domain in  $G= \left\{(t,x)| \quad \left|t-t_0 \right| \leq a, \quad \left|x-x_0\right| \leq b \right\}$\

Edit: the problem is
$$ \dot{x}(t)=f(t,x) \quad x(t_0)=x_0$$
With $f$ a Lipschitz function with constant $K$, and 
$$ \varphi_{n+1}=x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(s, \varphi_n(s))ds  $$
$$ \varphi_0=x_0$$

Comment: How do you define $\phi_n(t)$?

Comment: I haved edited!, is the sucesion of picard

Comment: What are your thoughts or attempts on this problem?

Comment: I passed almost two weeks trying to show this result , and well , I'm starting to thinking that problem is wrong , so, I came her for help

Comment: I'm not 100%, but [Gronwalls inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall%27s_inequality) _might_ help.